# Change breadcrump "shop" text WooCommerce in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

On this page: http://extremity3d.com/product-category/custom-orthoses/

I am looking to change the breadcrumb title to "Our Products" instead of "Shop"

Any ideas?

Comment: I _think_ you need to change the title of your shop page.

Comment: Already done. I believe this is something theme related

Comment: Theme's are the cause of a lot of my problems. In the [source code](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/986375862e6504b1f61e57b7ac071cd6b35bb722/includes/class-wc-breadcrumb.php#L95-L104) it looks like it *should* be the shop page's name, but in my testing site I don't have the shop crumb at all.

Comment: Most likely a theme error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the follows code snippet in your active theme's functions.php -

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_breadcrumb', 'modify_title_get_breadcrumb', 99, 2 );
function modify_title_get_breadcrumb( $crumbs, $breadcrumb ){
    if( ! is_product_category( 'custom-orthoses' ) ) return $crumbs; // Only custom-orthoses page

    // Check the 'Shop' item
    $check = __( 'Shop', 'woocommerce' );

    foreach( $crumbs as $key => $crumb ){
        if( $check === $crumb[0] ){
            // Change name
            $crumbs[$key][0] = __( 'Our Products', 'your-text-domain' );
        }
    }
    return $crumbs;
}
```

Comment: Nope, no luck. Thank you for attempting

Comment: The above codes is tested and woking properly. Its may be your theme issue ( the way its implemented breadcrumb )